# Fonts problems with online version with Gatsby & Netlify

Tags: gatsby, netlify, google-fonts

I'm working with gatsby, I deploy with netlify and I have a problem with google fonts. I'm using Raleway (H1) and Open Sans (body). I try to import fonts in css and it works locally and not with online version on netlify, I tried with "gatsby-plugin-google-font" works locally but not on netlify. I don't know where's the problem comes. You can check the website here : https://syter.fr
Any ideas ?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best guess without seeing your styling code — it *looks* like just a CSS specificity error, rather than anything particular to Gatsby or Netlify. You can verify in your devtools "Network" tab that the fonts are loaded correctly; and if you select one of the text elements rendering incorrectly, you see that the correct font (e.g., "Open Sans") is being masked by one or more other fonts. When disabled in devtools, you get the font you're going for:

[image]

Delving into your `index.css` file, I see that:

- `font-family` is declared within a `body` block multiple times; the one with `georgia,serif` is taking priority over the one with `Open Sans`.
- Similarly, you have rules with competing specificity for header elements; e.g.,

```css
h1,h2 {
  font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,Segoe UI,Roboto,Oxygen,Ubuntu,Cantarell,Fira Sans,Droid Sans,Helvetica Neue,sans-serif;
  // ...
}
// [futher down]
.landing h1 {
  font-family: Raleway,sans-serif
}
```

Any idea where these CSS rules are coming from? I'd start there.

---

Regarding why you're seeing different results running locally vs. on Netlify  — keep in mind what you see from running `gatsby develop` is **not** equivalent to what will be deployed, since Gatsby cuts some corners in "develop" mode to enable hot-reloading and whatnot, and heavily optimizes in "build" mode for production performance... 99% of the time the results are the same, but occasionally I've run into edge cases where they diverge. Have you tried running `gatsby build` locally and then testing the static output from that step (either with `gatsby serve` or just `cd`'ing into the public directory and launching an HTTP server pointing to `index.html`)? I'd bet that you'd be able to reproduce locally what you're seeing in Netlify that way, which could help in debugging.

A part ça, c'est très bien conçu

Hope this helps!